# executing a sh script from the cron

Tags: debian, shell, cron, sh

I have a test.sh script

```
#!/bin/sh
php /home/v/file.php
sh /root/x/some.sh
```

when I execute the file as root from command line it works.

```
sh /home/v/test.sh
```

when I set it to crontab -e (is the root cron), is not working

```
 * * * * * sh /home/v/test.sh
```

What do I do wrong?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [crontab to run bash script (ssh command in it) not working](http://serverfault.com/questions/186448/crontab-to-run-bash-script-ssh-command-in-it-not-working)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The enviroment for cron to run into is very very limited, try to always use full path for binaries.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/php /home/v/file.php
/bin/sh /root/x/some.sh
```

This considers that your php binary is in /usr/bin/php, please change that appropiately if it's not the case

Also try to add in top of your cron the MAILTO line in order to get a direct mail with any error that can happen during the execution

```
MAILTO=youraddress@yourmail.com
* * * * * sh /home/v/test.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probable the `php` binary isn't in the  default cron PATH. You should put the full path to your php binary in your script

`/usr/bin/php /home/v/file.php`

You should also provide a path for sh

`/bin/sh /root/x/some.sh`