# Crontab : Permission denied

Tags: samba, cron

My crontab(running as user) contains the following command

```
00-59 00-23 * * *  /usr/bin/smbget -R smb://192.168.10.32/Data -u USER -p PASSWORD
```

But I am getting an error as You don't have enough permissions to access `smb://192.168.10.32/Data/`

But the same command I can execute(running as user) from command line.

How to give permission to crontab to solve the issue.

Errors that I captured after executing:

```
00-59 00-23 * * *  /usr/bin/smbget -R smb://192.168.10.32/Data -u USER -p PASSWORD 2>> /path/to/samba.log
```

> Can't open directory smb://192.168.10.32/Data/a: Permission denied
>   Can't open directory smb://192.168.10.32/Data/b: Permission denied
>   Can't open directory smb://192.168.10.32/Data/c: Permission denied
>   You don't have enough permissions to access smb://192.168.10.32/Data/d
>   You don't have enough permissions to access smb://192.168.10.32/Data/e

### DEBUG Statements

```
params.c:OpenConfFile() - Unable to open configuration file "/home/USER/.smb/smb.conf":
    No such file or directory
params.c:OpenConfFile() - Unable to open configuration file "/home/USER/.smb/smb.conf.append":
    No such file or directory
Using netbios name MACHINE_NAME1.
Using workgroup WORKGROUP.
parsed path: fname='smb://192.168.10.32/Data' server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='' options=''
SMBC_check_options(): server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='' options=''
SMBC_server: server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
 -> server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
Connecting to 192.168.10.32 at port 445
 session request ok
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=46)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=<null>
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
 session setup ok
 tconx ok
Case sensitive: True
Server connect ok: //192.168.10.32/Data: 0x7f552dd6a290
received 10 entries (eos=1)
parsed path: fname='smb://192.168.10.32/Data/BSEEQ' server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='\BSEEQ' options=''
SMBC_check_options(): server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='\BSEEQ' options=''
SMBC_server: server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
 -> server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
Connecting to 192.168.10.32 at port 445
 session request ok
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=46)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=<null>
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
SPNEGO login failed: Account disabled
 session setup ok
parsed path: fname='smb://192.168.10.32/Data/MCX' server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='\MCX' options=''
SMBC_check_options(): server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='\MCX' options=''
SMBC_server: server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
 -> server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
Connecting to 192.168.10.32 at port 445
 session request ok
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=46)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=<null>
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
SPNEGO login failed: Account disabled
 session setup ok
parsed path: fname='smb://192.168.10.32/Data/NCDEX' server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='\NCDEX' options=''
SMBC_check_options(): server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='\NCDEX' options=''
SMBC_server: server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
 -> server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
Connecting to 192.168.10.32 at port 445
 session request ok
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=46)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=<null>
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
SPNEGO login failed: Account disabled
 session setup ok
parsed path: fname='smb://192.168.10.32/Data/NSEEQ' server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='\NSEEQ' options=''
SMBC_check_options(): server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='\NSEEQ' options=''
SMBC_server: server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
 -> server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
Connecting to 192.168.10.32 at port 445
 session request ok
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=46)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=<null>
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
SPNEGO login failed: Account disabled
 session setup ok
parsed path: fname='smb://192.168.10.32/Data/NSEFO' server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='\NSEFO' options=''
SMBC_check_options(): server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='\NSEFO' options=''
SMBC_server: server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
 -> server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
Connecting to 192.168.10.32 at port 445
 session request ok
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=46)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=<null>
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
SPNEGO login failed: Account disabled
 session setup ok
parsed path: fname='smb://192.168.10.32/Data/SCRIPMASTER' server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='\SCRIPMASTER' options=''
SMBC_check_options(): server='192.168.10.32' share='Data' path='\SCRIPMASTER' options=''
SMBC_server: server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
 -> server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
Connecting to 192.168.10.32 at port 445
 session request ok
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=46)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=<null>
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
SPNEGO login failed: Account disabled
 session setup ok
SMBC_server: server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
 -> server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
Connecting to 192.168.10.32 at port 445
 session request ok
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=46)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=<null>
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
SPNEGO login failed: Account disabled
 session setup ok


SMBC_server: server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
 -> server_n=[192.168.10.32] server=[192.168.10.32]
Connecting to 192.168.10.32 at port 445
 session request ok
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=46)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=<null>
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x628a8215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088215
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
  NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
  NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
SPNEGO login failed: Account disabled
 session setup ok
Using workgroup WORKGROUP, user USER
/home/USER
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue.  Apparently grabbing a recursive directory with smbget makes use of the current $USER environment variable.  Setting this variable to the same username as passed to smbget  gets around this, but still doesn't work for Cron Jobs.

This issue is documented here: https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8400

Here's a snippet from my script

```
pUSER=$USER     # store previous user
USER=$username  # new username
smbget -R -v -U -u "$username" "smb://server/c$/directory"
USER=$pUSER     # restore previous username
```

This works via the command line, but not when called from cron, very confused.

Hope this helps someone.

**EDIT**

After revisiting this, I realized that the same could be accomplished by using smbmount.  The code below is an example that works even if called from crontab.

```
username=myuser
domain=corp     #optional domain prefix
PASS=password123

smbmount  \\\\fileserver\\sharename /mnt/somedir -o user=$username,password=$PASS,dom=$domain
cp -R -u -v /mnt/somedir/* /destination_directory
umount /mnt/somedir
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing with this issue also and found my way here - this appears to be the relevant bug for this issue: https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6482

In that bug report it suggests that you embed the username and password inside the SMB URI, e.g.:

```
smbget -Rr smb://user:pass@host/sharename
```

I was getting permission denied issues however the above format works well.

**Please note:** If you use this method in your crontab then anyone with access to the box can fetch the credentials by examining a processlist. This may be acceptable for a private system though.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, after lots of recent pain with different but similar issues, that cron runs with `sh`, not your shell of choice (probably `bash`).  So, I would strongly recommend you check it properly as the functionality of `sh` is significantly limited in relation to bash, and all the built-ins, commands, and environment variables available with it.  Second, keep in mind escaping non-alphanumeric characters is always fun.  Thirdly, when all else fails, get the cron job to run smbget `00-59 00-23 * * * /usr/bin/smbget -R smb://192.168.10.32/Data -u USER -p PASSWORD 2>&1 >> /path/to/samba.log` to get some more detail.  Updating this post with that info might help us narrow down the issues.  Sorry, but per-user cron operations are not nearly as easy as they seem.

Comment: @alharaka I posted the issues

Comment: So can I presume you have checked a) the username and password in use and b) the discrete permissions on the files?  I understand you might have share access, but not the individual files in question? Second consideration, is this a domain SMB-CIFS (`ads` in Samba parlance) or something you have with its own local users on it? That makes a big difference in notation as far as I have experienced.

Comment: @alharaka but the same command it is working from command line. so how can it differs in the SMB-CIFS

Comment: This is looking fun, from the man page: `BUGS Permission denied is returned in some cases where the cause of the error is unknown (such as an illegally formatted smb:// url or trying to get a directory without -R turned on).` So, you might to try some variations, and more importantly and unfortunately, turn up the debug level with `-d`. And what is "working from the command line" mean? You were able to recursively download the entire folder without error?

Comment: yes it is recursively download the entire folder without error

Comment: I am kind of at a loss here.  Also, let me know what version of smbget and what happens when you run it wish `sh` explicitly from the command line. I would like to see the debug info because I suspect if that is the problem, maybe the way the parameters are passed is bad. So, maybe try `--username=username` and `--password=password` to see if that makes a difference.  Also you might want to put it [into Bash scripts and make sure environment variables are explicitly set](http://serverfault.com/questions/186448/crontab-to-run-bash-script-ssh-command-in-it-not-working). Again, show us the debug!

Comment: @alharaka I tried every combination it ends up with same error. I pasted the debug statements, please look.

Comment: @alharaka Version 3.4.7

Comment: @alharaka I can download a file by executing /usr/bin/smbget smb://192.168.10.32/Data/test.xml -u USER -p PASSWORD -o //home/USER/Data/test.xml 2>&1 >> /path/to/samba.log inside crontab

Comment: Great minds think alike.  I see you posted almost the same time as me on the Samba list.

Comment: @alharaka but I didn't get any response yet :(

Comment: Me neither.  Welcome to the wonderful word of open source.  If that is the case by the way, that you can get a single file, but not recursively go over the files in directory of the share, or the canonical share directory, what happens with versus without the trailing slash? `/usr/bin/smbget -R smb://192.168.10.32/Data/ -u USER -p PASSWORD` AND `/usr/bin/smbget -R smb://192.168.10.32/Data -u USER -p PASSWORD` give the same error code?

Comment: @alharaka I wrote a script which first mounts ,then copy and unmount. Working perfectly ..

Comment: But the script does not use `smbget`, yeah? Interesting.  Still curious what the deal was (have not checked the list, not sure if they explained why). Oh well.  Who knows what goes on when you put raw commands into crontab instead of a separate script. Another lost moral on a non-story.